# How to create Frequency table for categorical variable without gtsummary package

Tags: r, frequency, categorical-data, gtsummary

```r
gender <- c("male","female","female","male",NA)
test_resurt <- c("positive","negative",NA,"positive","negative")
homeless <- factor(c("yes","no","yes","no","no"))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(gender,test_resurt,homeless))
df
#>   gender test_resurt homeless
#> 1   male    positive        2
#> 2 female    negative        1
#> 3 female        <NA>        2
#> 4   male    positive        1
#> 5   <NA>    negative        1

library(gtsummary)
tbl <-tbl_summary(df)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDVi3.png)

How can I make the summary table without using gtsummary package?

Comment: do you want it to look exactly like that table or a table for each variable?

Comment: is there a specific issue you need addressed that isn't covered by your current code

Comment: I want to make that table in one table. (Not for a table for each variable). There is no specific issue. I know how to make a table for each variable but do not know how to make these tables into a table. My final goal is a summary table to pass to latex. I hope to use xtable but it doesn't matter.

Comment: ok no problem. one thing you might want to try is adding `as_hux_table()` to the end of your call. This will allow rmarkdown to render the table in latex if that is how you are doing it. if you want raw latex code so you can copy and paste into another document I don't think this will work though. example :  `trial %>%
  select(age, grade, response) %>%
  tbl_summary() %>% 
  gtsummary::as_hux_table()`

Comment: @Mike Thanks and I know the packages converting to Latex. I would like to make the same table without packages.